# getting error as pywinauto.application.ProcessNotFoundError: Process "mmc.exe" not found

Tags: pywinauto

Able to open printmanagement.msc using the below code. But when connecting to child process getting below error.

My code:
Application().start(r'cmd.exe /c mmc.exe printmanagement.msc', wait_for_idle=False)
app = Application(backend="uia").connect(path='mmc.exe')

Error:
pywinauto.application.ProcessNotFoundError: Could not find any accessible process with a module of 'mmc.exe'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because `mmc.exe` performs self-elevation (raising privileges to Administrator level). So you must run Python as Administrator to automate `mmc.exe`.

P.S. To run Python as Administrator right-click at Python / cmd.exe / IDE icon and choose popup menu item "run as Administrator". Also you can edit a shortcut properties to always run it as Administrator.

[image: run as Administrator]

[image: shortcut properties]